# how to advertise set_camera_info service?

Tags: ros, camera-info, camera-info-manager, camera-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to calibrate my camera using monocularcalibration node and it seems to be working fine. Now I have published my cameraInfo message but it ends up with an error saying set_camera_info service unavailable.

I tried to look into it and I found that I have to advertise this service using advertiseService() but I have some doubts.

I am using diamondback and I found a sensor_msgs::SetCameraInfo is the service provided. But somewhere I can also read that this service is controlled by camera_info_manager. But for diamondback it has been moved to image_common as per REP 104. It also talks about camera_parameter_parsers. I am confused how to proceed with this now. Does somebody have any idea about which package to be used exactly ?
My guess is that I have to somehow advertise the set_camera_info service but I am not sure if thats all is required by the calibration node or it also need camera_parameter_parser ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11385/how-to-advertise-set_camera_info-service-?/) by [abhinav](https://answers.ros.org/users/1080/abhinav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2011-09-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend using [camera_info_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager).

It will advertise the service for you, provide up-to-date `CameraInfo` data for you to publish, and store the updated calibration information. It uses [camera_calibration_parsers](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration_parsers), internally, so you need not worry about that.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3